# Generating multiple plots of categorical data counts to show trend over multiple years of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe countaining ~14000 rows and ~ 100 columns. I want to visualize how the frequencies of one column of categorical data have changed over time (a second column that is YYYY). Here is a simplified data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Year': ('1999','1999','1999','2000','2000','2001','2001','2002','2003'),
'Cat': ('A','A','C','B','B','B','C','D','D')
})
```

Using Pandas `groupby` and `reset_index`, I am left with the data of interest in a nice table.

```
df = df.groupby(['Year', 'Cat'])['Cat'].size()
df = df.reset_index(name='count')
```

For each year, I'd like a plot showing the frequency (count) of each Cat (even if 0). As the dataset spans 16 years, I'd like it in a 4x4 matrix of bar charts (the test dataset above would be limited to 2x2).

I have experience with basic plotting in matplotlib and seaborn, but my python experience is limited and I can't seem to crack this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reindex` to get zero values and then plot with seaborn `FacetGrid`. I used `value_counts` to get the dataframe first, but you could use `set_index` with the dataframe you have currently then use `reset_index`.

```
df2 = df.groupby('Year')['Cat'].value_counts()
df2.name = 'count'
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.index.levels[0], list('ABCD')], names=['Year', 'Cat'])
df2 = df2.reindex(ix, fill_value=0).reset_index()

g = sns.FacetGrid(df2, col='Year', col_wrap=2)
g.map(plt.bar, 'Cat', 'count')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried Facetgrid but was unable to arrive at the same result as you; I believe it had something to do with indexing.  Reserving this spot while I try something.

Comment: As the actual Cat column contains 15 different words (I now realize my example should have reflected this), `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.index.levels[0], df2['Cat'].unique()], names=['Year', 'Cat'])` did the trick. I now just need to arrange the labels vertically or resize the figure so I can read them. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: `g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but I hope this will help you.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Year': ('1999','1999','1999','2000','2000','2001','2001','2002','2003'),
'Cat': ('A','A','C','B','B','B','C','D','D')
})

labels = df.Year
Cat = df.Cat


x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, Cat, width, label='Cat')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scoring or I dunno')
ax.set_title('Some Letters')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()


def autolabel(rects):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roPWm.png)

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py

Comment: Thanks for your time Hans. The response by busybear accomplishes what I was after. My appologies if I was unclear.